# How to get ILT of $e^{-\alpha \sqrt{s}}/s^{3/2}$ by residue theorem?

Tags: residue-calculus, inverse-laplace

I posted some examples before such as
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{s}(s-A)}\right]=\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{A}+At}}{\sqrt{A}} - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\alpha \sqrt{r})}e^{-rt}}{r^{1/2}(r+A)}dr$$ and they have been solved by friends here ([How to get the inverse Laplace Transform?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770667/how-to-get-the-inverse-laplace-transform)).

I have been trying $$\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{s}}}{s^{3/2}}$$ by the same way but failed, because the result is $$-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\alpha \sqrt{r})}e^{-rt}}{r^{3/2}}dr$$ and it is divergent.

Moreover, $$\lim_{A \to 0}\left[\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{A}+At}}{\sqrt{A}} - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\alpha \sqrt{r})}e^{-rt}}{r^{1/2}(r+A)}dr]\right] \nrightarrow -\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{(\alpha \sqrt{r})}e^{-rt}}{r^{3/2}}dr$$

I think the branch cut along the minus axis might be wrong.

Would you like to help me?

Comment: What did you get for $f_A = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{s}}}{\sqrt{s}(s+A)}]$ ? When $\alpha >0,A>0$, with the principal branch of $\sqrt{s}$ and when we mean the inverse Laplace transform integral over a vertical line on $\Re(s) > 0$ then $f_A$ is continuous and it converges locally uniformly as $A\to 0$.

Comment: I reedited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica can fulfill this inverse Laplace transform:
$$\mathscr{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{e^{-\alpha \sqrt{s}}}{s^{3/2}}\right] = -\alpha + \frac{2\sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{\alpha^2}{4t}} +\alpha erf\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)$$.

But I really want to know this fulfillment by residue theorem.